# Using Custom and EF POCO Entities Together

Tags: entity-framework, poco

In one of my project EF 5.0 generate POCO entities for me under abcModel.tt, This is fine as I can use these in my project but if I apply validation in it then it get lost when I update .edmx from DB. so as a solution I also build all the entities by hand as well

Student.cs Generated by EF POCO
MyStudent.cs Generate by Me

One another reason to build MyStudent.cs is that DB column names are not well 
written for example

Generate by EF

```
Student.cs
{
    public int sid; // not good name due to table column name
    public string sfname; // not good name due to table column name
    public string slname; // not good name due to table column name
}
```

Build by me

```
MyStudent.cs
{
    public int StudentId;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}
```

So I like to know is my approach to have dual entities is ok?

**Note:**

1. I cannot change table column names because db is too big & already build by dba.
2. Only solution/suggestion with Data First approach is require.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this. I recommend creating a Data Transfer library and mapping your objects (like with AutoMapper). Then when you need to retrieve or save data to/from the database, call your DT and return a business object (your other class).

Something like this:

```
public class StudentDT
        {
            public StudentBO GetStudent(int id)
            {
                using (var db = new dbContext())
                {
                    var studentDB = db.Students.First(s => s.sid == id);
                    StudentBO sbo = Mapper.Map<StudentBO>(studentDB);
                    return sbo;
                }
            }

            public void SaveStudent(StudentBO sbo)
            {
                using (var db = new dbContext())
                {
                    var sdb = Mapper.Map<Student>(sbo);
                    db.Students.Add(sdb);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```